# How to pass function with parameters to dispatch function in setTimeout()

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, settimeout, axios, redux-thunk

I want to delay dispatch action after I get response from server.
I am using Redux_thunk. Here is my code which is not working.

```
    export const fetchActionCreator = ({ types, url, fetchOptions, dataKey }) => dispatch => {
    const actions = typesToActionCreators(types);
    dispatch(clientRequest());
    let mock_Response = [key="A",value="xyz"];

    return axios.get(url, fetchOptions)
        .then(response => response.data,
            error => console.log('an error occoured ' + error))
        .then(data => {
            console.log('time Before ' + new Date());
            setTimeout(() => { dispatch(actions.success(mock_Response, dataKey)) }, 4000);
            console.log('time After ' + new Date());
        });
};

function typeToActionCreator(type) {
    return typeof type === 'function' ? type : (payload, dataKey) => ({ type, payload, dataKey });
}

function typesToActionCreators(types) {
    const [request, success, failure] = types.map(typeToActionCreator);
    return { request, success, failure };
}
```

Can you tell me where am I making mistake?

Comment: why do you need setTimeout? you do dispatch in `then` which is how it supposed to be. Dispatch your `data` there.

Comment: yes right, after I put additional .then() I realized that I don't need it. But what would be syntax of setTimeout-dispatch in case I need it in future.